# Как браузер формирует http запрос?

Tags: java, http

Есть список ссылок на странице которые создаются в цикле и уходят запросом на сервер с `id` поста. Вот такой цикл:

```
<c:forEach var="propose" items="${requestScope.allProposes}">
    <ul>
        <a href="get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=${propose.id}">More</a>
        <hr>
    </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

При прохождении этого цикла получаются вот такие ссылки:

```
<a href="get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=1">More</a>
```

При отправлении запроса в вкладке network хрома создается вот такой header:

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/get_all_proposes/get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Вместо:

```
get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=1
```

Получается

```
get_all_proposes/get_all_proposes/get_propose_by_id?pId=1
```

В чем причина такого поведения? Как это поправить? Что-бы часть `get_all_proposes` не дублировалась?

Comment: Добавьте `/` в начало ссылки.

Comment: видимо сделать ссылку абсолютной. <a href='http://......'> внутри цикла

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Да это сработало. Большое спасибо.