# Почему не срабатывает AJAX запрос?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Есть `jsp` страница c списком предложений о продаже машин. На странице есть фильтр для получения предложений по моделям и маркам, который представляет из себя связанные `<option>`. Если пользователь выбрал марку то подгружаются модели `mark->model` при помощи Ajax. Сама выборка происходит при помощи `submit` отправки формы.

Проблема в том что после Ajax запросы работают только при первой выборке. Тоесть при **первом** заходе на страницу Ajax запросы и затем выборка по нажатию на `submit` формы работают правильно. Но при попытке снова сделать выборку все `<option>` пустые и не на что не реагируют.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Это форма:

```
<form method="get" action="get_all_proposes/select_propose_by_markmodel">

    <div>
        <select id="mark" name="mark" data-url="get_all_proposes/get_all_marks">
            <option value="">Select mark</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select id="model" name="model" data-url="get_all_proposes/get_model_by_mark">
            <option value="">Select model</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Select</button>

</form>
```

Это Ajax запросы:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get marks set.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_all_proposes/get_all_marks',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (data) {
            var select = $('#mark');

            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                var optionMark = $('<option>');
                optionMark.val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
            });
        }
    });

    //Get models set.
    $('#mark').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'get_all_proposes/get_model_by_mark',
            type : 'get',

            data : {
                'mark' : this.value
            },

            dataType: 'json',

            success : function(data) {
                var optionModel = $('#model');

                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    optionModel.append($('<option>').val(value).text(value));
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: в консоли есть ошибки? запросы идут?

Comment: А где очищение селекта `model` перед перезаполнением? "все <option> пустые" - а сколько их "всех"?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да консоль все показала надо было абсолютные пути указывать. Я так и не понял как браузер формирует запросы по относительным путям. Смущает что IDE подчеркивает использование абсолютных путей в аттрибуте `form action` пишет что не рекомендовано я спрашивал в этом вопросе но пока никто не ответил как именно брузер работает с относительными путями:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700755/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-http-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Comment: если путь не начинается со **/**, то он относительный. я jsp не использую.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman какая есть альтернатива выгодно отличающаяся от jsp?

Comment: thymeleaf например, но я и его не использую. есть специально обученные люди, которые делают хороший фронтенд.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman ну какие возможности  которых нет в  `jsp`+`jstl`?

Comment: основаная **less is more**